# Process pool results without waiting for all tasks to finish

Tags: python, performance, asynchronous, concurrency, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
from time import sleep
import random
import string
import uuid
import os
import glob



def task_a(param1, param2, mydata):

    thread_id = str(uuid.uuid4().hex)   # this may not be robust enough to guarantee no collisions, address
    output_filename = ''.join([str(thread_id),'.txt'])
    # part 1 - create output file for task_b to use
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in mydata:
            outfile.write(line)
    # part 2 - do some extra stuff (whilst task_b is running)
    sleep(5)
    print('Task A finished')
    return output_filename # not interested in return val


def task_b(expected_num_files):
    processed_files = 0
    while processed_files<expected_num_files:
        print('I am task_b, waiting for {} files ({} so far)'.format(expected_num_files, processed_files))
        path_to_search = ''
        for filename in glob.iglob(path_to_search + '*.txt', recursive=True):
            print('Got file : {}'.format(filename))
            # would do something complicated here
            os.rename(filename, filename+'.done')
            processed_files+=1
        sleep(10)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    param1 = ''     # dummy variable, need to support in solution
    param2 = ''     # dummy variable, need to support in solution

    num_workers = 2
    full_data = [[random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(100)]
    print(full_data)
    for i in range(0, len(full_data), num_workers):
        print('Going to process {}'.format(full_data[i:i+num_workers]))
        p = Pool(num_workers)
        task_a_func = partial(task_a, param1, param2)
        results = p.map(task_a_func, full_data[i:i+num_workers])
        p.close()
        p.join()
        task_b(expected_num_files=num_workers) # want this running sooner
        print('Iteration {} complete'.format(i))
        #want to wait for task_a's and task_b to finish
```

I'm having trouble scheduling these tasks to run concurrently.

task_a is a multiprocessing pool that produces an output file part way through it execution.

task_b MUST process the output files sequentially can be in any order (can be as soon as they are available), WHILST task_a continues to run (it will no longer change the output file)

The next iteration must only start when both all task_a's have completed AND task_b has completed.

The toy code I have posted obviously waits for task_a's to fully complete before task_b is started (which is not what I want)

I have looked at multiprocessing / subprocess etc. but **cannot find a way to launch both the pool and the single task_b process concurrently AND wait for BOTH to finish.**

task_b is written as if it could be changed to an external script, but I am still stuck on how manage the execution.

Should I effectively merge code from task_b into task_a and somehow pass a flag to ensure one worker per pool 'runs the task_b code' via a if/else - at least then I would just be waiting on the pool to complete?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interprocess queue to communicate the filenames between task a and task b.

Also, initializing pool repeatedly inside the loop is harmful and unnecessarily slow.
Its better to initialize the pool once in the beginning.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Event
from functools import partial
from time import sleep
import random
import string
import uuid
import os
import glob



def task_a(param1, param2, queue, mydata):
    thread_id = str(uuid.uuid4().hex)
    output_filename = ''.join([str(thread_id),'.txt'])
    output_filename = 'data/' + output_filename
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in mydata:
            outfile.write(line)
    print(f'{thread_id}: Task A file write complete for data {mydata}')
    queue.put(output_filename)
    print('Task A finished')


def task_b(queue, num_workers, data_size, event_task_b_done):
    print('Task b started!')
    processed_files = 0
    while True:
        filename = queue.get()
        if filename == 'QUIT':
            # Whenever you want task_b to quit, just push 'quit' to the queue
            print('Task b quitting')
            break
        print('Got file : {}'.format(filename))
        os.rename(filename, filename+'.done')
        processed_files+=1
        print(f'Have processed {processed_files} so far!')
        if (processed_files % num_workers == 0) or (processed_files ==  data_size):
            event_task_b_done.set()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    param1 = ''     # dummy variable, need to support in solution
    param2 = ''     # dummy variable, need to support in solution


    num_workers = 2
    data_size = 100
    full_data = [[random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(data_size)]
    mgr = Manager()
    queue = mgr.Queue()
    event_task_b_done = mgr.Event()
    # One extra worker for task b
    p = Pool(num_workers + 1)
    p.apply_async(task_b, args=(queue, num_workers, data_size, event_task_b_done))
    task_a_func = partial(task_a, param1, param2, queue)
    for i in range(0, len(full_data), num_workers):
        data = full_data[i:i+num_workers]
        print('Going to process {}'.format(data))
        p.map_async(task_a_func, full_data[i:i+num_workers])
        print(f'Waiting for task b to process all {num_workers} files...')
        event_task_b_done.wait()
        event_task_b_done.clear()
        print('Iteration {} complete'.format(i))
    queue.put('QUIT')
    p.close()
    p.join()
    exit(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, will play, but I need to only start next iteration when 'task_a part 2' has finished AND task_b has completed for the current iteration. Not obvious from toy example, but in question. This is why I had p.join() etc. in loop.

Comment: I know. In my code, next iteration will start only after task a and b both are done. Thats the purpose of `event_task_b_done.wait()`. Have you tried running it?

Comment: Yes, add sleep after queue.put in task_a (this is part #2) and see next loop iter (although not next p.map..) start before task_a finishes. I think I can handle this with some extra queue messaging - make task_b wait on files AND num_workers * 'Finished' messages per iter ? Sorry, this may be unclear from my toy example, but real-world I have extra tasks at beginning of loop that must wait on task_a to complete fully, not just after output file is produced.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I added sleep and it works as expected. [Output](http://collabedit.com/cp7p5)

Comment: In output I am interpreting: 10=end of first iter, 11=start of 2nd loop iter, 13&14 = task_a finishes for FIRST iter,  15&16 = task_a working on 2nd iter. So, in my mind (I may be misunderstanding and I appreciate your help) - Line 13&14 should be before 10?

Comment: Dont worry too much about the `Task A finished` statement. Actually they are free to execute any time since they are written after the `queue.put()`.  An easy way to verify if its working properly is that `Iteration complete` should only be printed after 2 occurences of  `Have processed .... files so far. ` I can assure you that the program is correct.